# JSONPath exclude as separate JSON

Tags: javascript, json, jsonpath

I have a complex JSON Structure . I wan't to exclude a part and get the list in two buckets. Say One as "inclusions" and another as "exclusions".
Sample JSON is given below.

```
{
"Item": {
    "Items": [{
        "Items": [{
            "category": "fruit",
            "Item": {
                "Items": [{
                    "Text": "Apple"
                },
                {
                    "Text": "Orange"
                },
                {
                    "Text": "Grapes"
                },
                {
                    "Text": "Guava"
                }],
                "Types": ["Value",
                "Value",
                "Value",
                "Value"]
            },
            "Type": "Or"
        },
        {
            "category": "fruit",
            "Item": {
                "Text": "Pineapple"
            },
            "Type": "Value"
        }],
        "Types": ["Constraint",
        "Constraint"]
    },
    {
        "category": "fruit",
        "Item": {
            "Text": "Banana"
        },
        "Type": "Value"
    }],
    "Types": ["Not",
    "Constraint"]
},
"Type": "And"}
```

Here we have category fruits where We Apple,Orange ,Grapes and Guava are with "OR" and pineapple with "AND" Type and Banana is with "Not" .Once I Try

```
Item..Items[?(@.category='fruit')]..Text
```

It returns me

```
  [   "Banana",   "Apple",   "Orange",   "Grapes",   "Guava", "Pineapple"]
```

But I want List to be

```
{["Apple",     "Orange",       "Grapes",       "Guava",    "Pineapple"  ]
},{["Banana"]}
```

Is there a way in JSON Path to get something of similar structure

Comment: A D3 Nest is probably the way to go here

Answer (score 1):

That may be not the answer you expected, but I don't think that's possible with JsonPath.

Quote from [jayway/JsonPath](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath)

> When evaluating a path you need to understand the concept of when a path is definite. A path is indefinite if it contains:

- .. - a deep scan operator
- ?() - an expression
- [,  (, )] - multiple array indexes

> Indefinite paths always returns a list (as represented by current JsonProvider).

So your result will always be a list. What you already have is the closest you can get, I think.

Answer (score 1):

That can not be done using JSONPath.